# Add Expires headers load from third party url

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, js-css

I am using Magento 1.9.3. I have an issue GT Metrix says "add expire headers" for third party URL.

Looks like bellow in GT Metrix.

```
There are 4 static components without a far-future expiration date.

    https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700
    https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900
    http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4
    https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/f1e65db1bc67ed8/?lid=115&payload=%7B%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D
```

any help how to add expires header for on-line/third party js/css files.

Answer (score 1):

**Expires Headers**

You can't control expires headers for content you're loading from a different site. Options you could consider:

1. Continue using external sites; in this case, these are pretty well behaved and your performance will probably be pretty good. Just ignore the low grade that GT Metrix is giving you.